# How can I bring in kafka-avro-console-producer into a kubernetes deployment at startup?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a kubernetes deployment of kafka and I want to add the services in this repo (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry) into it with the goal being I want to use the kafka-avro-console-producer script.

I have seen it before where the script is in the kafka/bin with the other console producer/consumer scripts and the like. But I can't figure out what to do to get that again.

I expect there is a way to the deployment file or something, but I am just stuck and not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

The console producer scripts are not separately downloadable. If you already have a schema registry service with `cp-schema-registry` image, then exec into that, and you have those scripts available.

Or, you could `mvn package` that repo, then search the `bin` directory, and build your own docker image.

Otherwise, you could simply write code in something like [Python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py) or [Javascript](https://kafkajs.github.io/confluent-schema-registry/docs/usage-with-kafkajs/) that you have more control than CLI over, and run from outside of your cluster.

Comment: I did exec into the schema registry pod but can't find the scripts. Do you know what the file directory they should be under is?

Comment: They should already be on the PATH. E.g. I can run this `docker run --rm --entrypoint=kafka-avro-console-producer confluentinc/cp-schema-registry --help` ... But `/usr/bin`. Or, like I said, I find actual programs to be more flexible than CLI commands

Comment: Ok thanks. Yea actual programs are easier, but without getting into it and going off topic, using the script is only route I can use right now.